# Why a program returns unreadable characters?

Tags: c, printf

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int dict, char **jumbles) {
    const char *j = *jumbles;
    FILE *jumbles_file = fopen(j ,"r");
    char jumbles_words[52];
    while (fgets(jumbles_words, sizeof(jumbles_words), jumbles_file)) {
        printf("%s", jumbles_words);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just ignore the parameter `int dict`.

My point is to take input `char **jumbles` and print out line by line. But when I run the program.

Output is unreadable. What are the reasons and how to fix this?

```
root@MSI:~# ./unscramble dictionary.txt jumbles.txt
��-o.2ck_chk_failGLIBC_2.34__/D=�.Dd����}.�dH�%(E���E�H��H��H��u˸���P
  � 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0@1.oglobal_dtors_auxfini_array_entryay_entryEH_FRAME_HDRn@GLIBC_2.34niets@GLIBC_2.2.5andleIBC_2.2.5xa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5trtabontamemmenti
```

Comment: Function `fgets` needs space for a null (0) character at the end of the input array. So change `sizeof(jumbles_words)` to `sizeof(jumbles_words) - 1`.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb "The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s until n-1 bytes are read" - [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

Comment: `dict` and `jumbles` are just `argc` and `argv` with different names. You're reading the file `argv[0]` which is the executable so it doesn't contain text data.

Comment: `&**jumbles` the address of the data at `*jumbles?`  That's just `*jumbles` isn't it?

Comment: @linggS. bbbbbbbbb's suggestion was totally wrong, that's why.

Comment: @interjay then what i should do?

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do here, but maybe try changing the very strange `const char *j = &**jumbles;` to the more reasonable (and slightly different) `const char *j = jumbles[1];`.

Comment: *Just ignore the parameter `int dict`* I'm sorry, but this is a little bit like a guy with an iron bar through his head walking into a doctor's office and saying "Hey, Doc, ignore the bar through my head, but can you help me with this terrible headache I've got?" :-)

Comment: You should read a guide about handling command-line arguments in C. One example from Google: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/

Comment: Aha. Finally read the example in your post. Looks like it's (b).  So definitely go with `const char *j = jumbles[1];`, or maybe even `const char *j = jumbles[2];`.

Comment: @SteveSummit actually i also need to read file called `dict`, but because it is `int` i still find the way to convert it in order to use `fgets`, btw do you know how to convert it?

Comment: @linggS. When you invoke your program with two command-line arguments, they do *not* come through as `main(argument1, argument2)`.  You need to take interjay's suggestion and read up on this.  There are 1,000,000 places that will tell you how command-line arguments work in C.  C is not a language you can learn by guessing, or by writing down things that you just think will work.

Comment: One more tip: Please don't do work like this when logged in as root!  You don't need to be root to compile and run a C program.  But if one of your programs goes badly wrong, if you're running as root it can do a *lot* of damage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show uses argv[0] as input file. It is the binary program itself (normally), so you read binary gibberish.

Here's your code with some changes at the start, explanations in comments. The actual code may have other bugs (in particular, you don't check if `fopen` succeeds), but this should solve the problem you ask about:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Use normal main argument names
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Two arguments needed
    if (argc != 3) {
        puts("Two arguments expected!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // arv[0] is program name

    // argv[1] is dictionary file, ignored 

    const char *j = argv[2]; // jumbles file

    // below code has no changes

    FILE *jumbles_file = fopen(j ,"r");
    char jumbles_words[52];
    while(fgets(jumbles_words, sizeof(jumbles_words), jumbles_file)) {
        printf("%s", jumbles_words);
    }
    return 0;
}
```